# check two constrains in subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I have two tables like this

*FirstTable*

Name      Age     District

AAA       20       North

BBB       21       South

CCC       19       West

and

*SecondTable*

Name   Age   District

ZZZ    19    North

YYY    20    South

XXX    21    North

WWW    24    North

VVV    20    North

UUU    20    West

so my goal is get the first row name of first table (this case 'AAA') and match from second table who live in same district and age is equal or greater than one or less than one (this case age=20,age=19,ane=21 from first table).

to do that I wrote a query like this

SELECT *

FROM Secondtable

WHERE Age=(SELECT Age FROM FristTatle WHERE Name='AAA') OR

```
  Age+1=(SELECT Age FROM FristTatle WHERE Name='AAA') OR

  Age-1=(SELECT Age FROM FristTatle WHERE Name='AAA')

  AND

  District=(SELECT District FROM FirstTable WHERE Name='AAA')
```

but this return names who in different District (here it returns YYY and UUU). is there any problem in my query???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from FirstTable
inner join SecondTable
on SecondTable.District = FirstTable.District And
(SecondTable.Age - FirstTable.Age) between -1 and 1
where FirstTable.Name = 'AAA';
```

should do it